# SQL for hierarchical relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table where products are categorised based on hierarchical relationship like a tree structure. I'm having to select a category and all subcategories at any level. See the picture below:

[image]

e.g. i want an sql statement that when i query passing the id=11, it returns me (19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)

Answer (score 11):

There are several different ways to store heirarchical data in MySQL. Check out Bill Karwin's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) that demonstrates four options.

- Adjacency List
- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

You are using the **adjacency list** model for storing heirarchical data, but unfortunately this is the **hardest** model you could choose for querying subtrees.

[image: nested sets query subtree]

Your options are:

- Change to a different model.
- Restrict queries to n levels deep.
- Use a stored procedure to query recursively. For more information about this, see Quassnoi's series of articles - [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `Products` 
WHERE parentId IN (
    SELECT id FROM `Products` 
    WHERE parentId = 11)
```

NOTE: This won't work if your hierarchy is deeper than 2 levels.

Answer (score 1):

Could you change your data-structure a little to include a computed linage column. There's a [great article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql) which shows you the generic concept (ignore the database type).

Basically your computed linage column should contain the list of parents in it for example

Item 26 would contain `\11\`

If you had a subitem you could have

`\11\subitem\`

Then you can simply do a like check on  your linage table, its much faster than a iterative search, and you could do create it using a stored proc or triggers.

```
Node    ParentNode  EmployeeID  Depth   Lineage
100        NULL         1001            0   /
101        100          1002            1   /100/
102        101          1003            2   /100/101/
103        102          1004            3   /100/101/102/
104        102          1005            3   /100/101/102/
105        102          1006            3   /100/101/102/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is messy, and you'll have to do n unions, where n is how deep your hierarchy is, but it should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
    SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId = 11)
UNION
SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
    SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
         SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId = 11))
UNION
SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
    SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
        SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId IN (
             SELECT id FROM `Products` WHERE parentId = 11)))
```