# How to output parent child relationships within tables in sql?

Tags: sql, join, relationship

I have Table1 which shows the child and parent relationships between products. How to I get the output table with sql? Basically, Input table shows that B is a child of A and B1 and B2 are child of B. The output would need to show that as well, and also that B1 and B2 are child of A.

Comment: What database platform?

Comment: I need to do this is ANSI sql format. Can do it in any platform as long as database specific functions are not used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL for hierarchical relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382866/sql-for-hierarchical-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

As an example, you could do:

```
SELECT childproduct, parentproduct
FROM product_table
START WITH parentproduct = 'Product A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR childproduct = parentproduct;
```

Note: This assumed that you know the root (top level) element is 'Product A'. Although it may work without it too.

Comment: This returns only the child parent pair that IMMEDIATELY follows each other: The result from your query will be:

CHILD        PARENT
Product B         Product A...
Product B1 Product B...
Product B2 Product B...
Product D Product B...
Product D1 Product D...
Product E1 Product D1...
Product E2 Product D1...
Product C Product A...

Comment: @Sterls thanks for pointing it out. And also, checked out your answer on sqlfiddle - that's pretty cool! I could not test the answer myself because I didn't have oracle in my laptop.

Comment: No problem :) You should be able to change the DB engine on sql fiddle from the menu bar at the top and test it with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is shown in this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87657/61

You do need to use a Hierarchical Query as shown below:

```
SELECT ChildProduct, CONNECT_BY_ROOT ParentProduct
FROM table_name
WHERE LEVEL >= 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR ChildProduct = ParentProduct
```

|      CHILD | CONNECT_BY_ROOTPARENT |
|------------|-----------------------|
|  Product B |             Product A |
| Product B1 |             Product A |
| Product B2 |             Product A |
|  Product C |             Product A |
|  Product D |             Product A |
| Product D1 |             Product A |
| Product E1 |             Product A |
| Product E2 |             Product A |
| Product B1 |             Product B |
| Product B2 |             Product B |
| Product D1 |             Product D |
| Product E1 |             Product D |
| Product E2 |             Product D |
| Product E1 |            Product D1 |
| Product E2 |            Product D1 |

Comment: Is this in ANSI sql format? Or is this specific to Oracle? Thanks.